# Does open connection block database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, parallel-processing, database-connection

I have a (Python) program that checks if a table (given by its name) exists in a (sqlite) database. If the table does not exist, the program creates the table.

My problem is parallel processes. It can happen that that a process checks if a table exists, it sees that the table does not exist and decides to add the table, but another process adds the table first and then, when the first process tries to add the table, it already exists.

My question is if there are some mechanisms to temporally block other processes from interaction with the data bases. For example, when the first process starts to interact with the databases, the databases becomes "closed" for other processes. Then the first process checks if table exists, then it sees that the table does not exists, it also "knows" that the table will not be created by any other process (because they are "blocked"), the the process creates the table and unblock the databases (i.e. allows other process to interact with the database).

I assume that the above described mechanism can be implemented by opening and closing connections. When one connection is open, no other connections can be opened. Is my assumption correct? If not, are there other ways to implement the above described "blocking" mechanism? Or, such mechanism are considered as "bad practice"?

Comment: Read the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) docs about transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't lock when you don't have to! Use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the_table ....
```

Comment: In this particular case we can solve the problem by combining two commands ("check if exist" and "create") into one. However, I would like to know if it is possible to "lock" in general (for the cases in which it is impossible or hard to get a desired result with one sql command).

Comment: Yes, using a transaction. Usually you would like to try your very hardest to make sure your transactions don't invalidate each other (locking whole tables is a pretty good sign that something is broken).